# C initialization bus error

Tags: c, bus

I am creating a binary tree as small project to learn C. Here is all the code you need.

```
typedef struct {
  int value;
  struct Node *leftchild;
  struct Node *rightchild;
  struct Node *parent;
} Node;

typedef struct {
  Node *root;
} BinaryTree;

void newBT( BinaryTree *_bt ) {
  _bt->root = 0;
  return;
};

Node* makeNode(int _value ) {
  Node *node;
  node->value = _value;
  node->leftchild = 0;
  node->rightchild = 0;
  node->parent = 0;
  return node;
};

void insert( BinaryTree* _bt, int _value ) {
  _bt->root = makeNode(_value);
  return;
};
```

Now, I have tested my makeNode() function and it works as intended and I checked it using a has() function which traverses the list and returns true if it finds a node with the given value, returns false otherwise. It is the first commented out line in main() below. When I pass my BinaryTree into insert() and declare the same line using a pointer I get a Bus error:10.

```
int main () {
  BinaryTree bt;
  newBT(&bt);
  //bt.root = makeNode(14);
  insert(&bt, 14);
  //printf("%d \n", has(&bt, 14));
  return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makeNode` is writing to the (undefined) address pointed to by an uninitialised pointer.  You don't own the memory this points to so attempting to write to it results in undefined behaviour; a crash is a valid (and often useful) example of undefined behaviour.

You need to allocate memory here

```
Node* makeNode(int _value ) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ...
```

Make sure to return this memory to the system - by calling `free(node)` - when you remove a node from your list.

Comment: anything is a valid example of undefined behavior :) (format hard drive, print works of Shakespeare, turn on toaster). I think you mean 'common example'